# How can weka in Java classify one sample and print the result rather than read arff files?

Tags: machine-learning, weka

Because I read the non-classify samples line by line, and I want to append the classify result to the end of each line, I have load the weka model file. Can I use weka in java to classify one sample rather than read arff files?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You could use [Evaluation.evaluationForSingleInstance](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html#evaluationForSingleInstance(double[],%20weka.core.Instance,%20boolean)) to estimate for a single case.